# How to parse a string of data into key-value pairs and append it into "put" method?

Tags: string, scala, key-value, put

I have a string of data and want to parse it into key/value pairs and then append it to “put” method and encode then to GenericRecord. However, it doesn’t work out and I would be grateful for a hint how to do it.

I converted a string into the list of strings, but apperently here just two strings are expected. Would be grateful for any ideas how to solve the issue.

```
data = "{"name":"John", "surname":"Peterson", "country":"France", “amount”: null}"

val parsedData = data.split(",").map(x => {val y = x.split(":");(y(0),y(1))}).map(x => (x._1,x._2)).toList
```

//output type here List[(String, String)]

```
rec.put(parsedData)
```

//input for “put” method - public void put(String key, Object value)

Expected results: to append data dynamically as they come from a message:

```
rec.put("name", "John")
rec.put("surname", "Peterson")
rec.put("country", "France")
rec.put(“amount”, null)
```

Comment: `parsedData.foreach { case (key, value) => rec.put(key, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more elegant way of doing what you asked for.

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

val data = "{"name":"John", "surname":"Peterson", "country":"France", “amount”: null}"
val parsedData: Map[String, String] = parse(data).extract[Map[String, String]]

parsedData.foreach { case (key, value) => rec.put(key, value) }
```

Comment: Thanks for help and for idea with json tools!